# Can't move background image up on website

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I'm trying to add a background image to my timeline on a website, but I can't seem to move my background image up and down without it shrinking. It almost seems like there's some invisible bar keeping me from moving the image up. If it moves up, it just shrinks.

edit: Sorry for the confusion. I am wanting to move the image up in the background of the timeline. I can't move it up using top.

Initially I couldn't even get the image to show up, but now I need to use the
background-image: cover
property and it's not working as expected. I'm doing something wrong.

What I've tried:

1. adjusting the height and width of my elements
2. using Top to move the background image up/down

Here's the code for the timeline and it's styling sheets:

```css
html {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(#FF9940, white);
  font-weight: normal;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Raleway;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 53px;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px grey;
  background-color: #1E2752;
  text-align: center;
  border: 5px solid black;
  color: #FCFCFF;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

li {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 19px 16px;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  right: -100px;
}

li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #FF9940;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

ul {
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  top: 28px;
  left: 23px;
  right: 23px;
  width: 100%;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
}

h2 p {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.right-button {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 47px
}

.other-button {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

#timeline {
  font-family: tahoma;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.75;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  width: 650px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #031625;
}

.t1-item:before,
.t1-item:after {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.t1-item {
  padding: 25px;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
  margin-top: 20rem;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: width 0.5s ease;
}

.t1-item:after {
  background: rgba(3, 22, 37, 0.85);
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s ease;
}

.t1-item:before {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 75%);
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) translateY(50%);
  transition: opacity .5s ease, transform .5s ease;
}

.t1-item:hover {
  width: 30%;
}

.t1-item:hover:after {
  opacity: 0;
}

.t1-item:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) translateY(0);
  transition: opacity 1s ease, transform 1s ease .25s;
}

.t1-item:hover .t1-content {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: all .75s ease .5s;
}

.t1-item:hover .t1-bg {
  filter: grayscale(0);
}

.t1-content {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) translateY(25px);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0.1618em;
  top: 55%;
  opacity: 0%;
}

.t1-content h3 {
  font-family: tahoma;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #1779cf;
  font-size: 1.44rem;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.t1-year {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.t1-year p {
  font-family: tahoma;
  font-size: 1.628rem;
  line-height: 0;
}

.t1-bg {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  transition: filter .5se ease;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title> Isabelle Kreienbrink </title>
  <link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <h1> Isabelle Kreienbrink </h1>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#resume">Resume</a></li>
    <li><a href="#academics">Academics</a></li>
    <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
    <li class="right-button"><a href="#contacts">Contact Info</a></li>
    <li class="other-button"><a href="#other">Test</a></li>
    <li class="other-button"><a href="#other">Testing</a></li>
  </ul>
  <h2> Welcome to my website!
    <p> I hope you learn a little about me while you're here. </p>
  </h2>



  <section id="timeline">
    <div class="t1-item">
      <div class="t1-bg" style="background-image:url(https://www.eschoolnews.com/files/2016/12/computer-science-education-600x400.jpg); height: 100%; width: 100%;">
      </div>

      <div class="t1-year">
        <p class="f2 heading">2014</p>
      </div>

      <div class="t1-content">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor </h3>
        <p>
          test
        </p>
      </div>

    </div>



    <div class="t1-item">
      <div class="t1-bg" style="background-image:url(https://www.eschoolnews.com/files/2016/12/computer-science-education-600x400.jpg) height: 100%, width: 100%"></div>
      <div class="t1-year">
        <p class="f2 heading">2015</p>
      </div>

      <div class="t1-content">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor </h3>
        <p>
          test
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="t1-item">
      <div class="t1-bg" style="background-image:url(001.jpeg)"></div>

      <div class="t1-year">
        <p class="f2 heading">2016</p>
      </div>

      <div class="t1-content">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor </h3>
        <p>
          test
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>



  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: the backgound of elements in timeline ?

Comment: Your post is not clear, how you wanna move the background image? what's the scenario of movement? hover? click? scroll?

Comment: Maybe removing `margin-top: 20rem;` from `.t1-item` also the styles in the style attribute of the images are missing semicolons.

Comment: Please check my response here is a link - https://jsfiddle.net/e6hymbf8/

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am wanting to move the image up in the example I posted. the grey one in the background of the timeline. I can't move it up using top.

Comment: @ZohirSalak yes that was the issue. thank you for the recommendation, my problem is solved!